# for set $R^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

$R^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$, I found that the boundary of this set $(0,0)$ and interior of set = $R^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$. However, it confused me because Set \ boundary of set should be interior of this set and I was stuck. Is my way correct?

Comment: It should be closure of set without boundary is interior.

Comment: It is true here that the set minus the boundary is the interior. Where does the confusion come from?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: is $R^2$ \ {$(0,0)$} minus {$(0,0)$} = $R^2$ \ {$(0,0)$} ? It confused me

Comment: Removing the point $(0,0)$ once is same as removing it twice!.

Comment: Yes. The set difference $A \setminus B$ is defined as $\{x \in A ~~ \text{and} ~~ x \not\in B\}$:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closure of the set $X = \Bbb R^2 \setminus \{(0,0)\}$ is $\operatorname{cl} X = \Bbb R^2$. As $X$ is open by definition its interior is $\operatorname{int} X = X$. Hence its boundary is $\operatorname{bd} X = \operatorname{cl} X \setminus \operatorname{int} X = \{(0,0)\}$. It also holds that $\operatorname{int} X = \operatorname{cl} X \setminus \operatorname{bd} X = (\Bbb R^2 \setminus\{(0,0)\})\setminus\{(0,0)\} = \Bbb R^2 \setminus \{(0,0)\} = X$.